# COUNTIF Across Multiple "renamed" worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, countif

What I am trying to do is count a single column from every sheet and indentify how many pass, fail and N/A. One more forumla for each as they will be displayed in different cells (One cell for pass, one for fail and one N/A). Numerous threads online, but the solution does not work in my scenario.

I can count column individual in each cell using the following forumla:

```
=COUNTIF('Users - External '!F2:F27,"Pass")
=COUNTIF('Users - External '!F2:F27,"Fail")
=COUNTIF('Users - External '!F2:F27,"N/A")
```

When I try to count the column (F Column) across all the spreadsheets I get an error, I used the following forumla in another sheet while inserting each sheet name into its own cell (In this case A1:A3 had three of my sheet names - there is more), but I did not get a result. Just a reference (#REF!) Error. Is it an issue with how my tabs are named?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT( "'"& A1:A3 &"'!F2:F1000"),"Pass"))
```

[image]

I am not looking for a VBA solution.

Comment: The text is off.  It appears you have an space at the end of the sheet name.  That same space must be in the cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner Wow. This is why its good to step away sometimes and get a breather. Thanks Scott. If you would like to post as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is space in you sheet name but you have not entered the same in `A1:A3` as said by  @Scott Craner .

The formula is perfect, only issue with sheet names. you have to re-enter with space in end at `A1:A3` or else you have to remove space at end in you three sheets. That's the reason it's giving **#REF!** Error.

Here you go for an sample snap, the formula is working perfect @champ Loz :-)

[image]